# What can I do to resolve low FPS problems on AMD Graphics?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics

Two days ago I bought Hp dv6t with Radeon 7690m xt. When I run cpu and gpu benchmark on Cinebench 11.5, I got 5.01 cpu and 48.16 FPS for gpu.

After I installed updates from HP notification center, the FPS and CPU score has dropped significantly, now on cinebench I get 4.29 for cpu and 29.17 FPS for gpu. What should I do to reatain previous performance of the computer.

I didn't install any junk on the computer yet and I haven't backup windows 7.

Comment: please ask **only one** question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the power settings of your windows 7 is set to "High performance" The installation of HP driver updates might have set these settings to "Balanced" or even "Power saver" wich in turn would affect the performance of your notebook.

Comment: more over My pc has started overheating. I am getting around 55-60 C on idle and 95-100 C on heavy gaming and benchmarking. Do you know how do I increase the fan speed, cuz there is no such option in the bios

Comment: Sadly, I do not know. However, I once had an HP Pavilion notebook. And if I remember correctly, I could choose different fan options in the BIOS. Like "always on" and "temperature controlled".

Answer (score 0):

Remove your graphics card drivers and try installing the newest ones found on AMDs website. I've had issues with HP notification center giving out old or incorrect drivers. A poor choice of GFX driver on HPs part is likely the culprit.

Do yourself a favor and uninstall the HP notification center and do your driver updates when needed and also by hand to ensure that your getting the best available.

I'm a big advocate of if it ain't broke don't fix it. If your current drivers are working perfectly, why bother messing with them? Enthusiasts will obviously disagree on this point, but the average desktop user normally has no concept of what a driver is or when it makes sense to upgrade.